# How to add multiple new columns with when condition in pyspark dataframe?

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

```
I need to add two new columns to my existing pyspark dataframe.
Below is my sample data:

Section   Grade     Promotion_grade Section_team
Admin       C       
Account     B       
IT          B   

condition :

If Section = Admin then Promotion_grade = B
If Section = Account then Promotion_grade = A
If Section = IT then
             If Grade = C then Promotion_grade = B & Section_team= team1
             If Grade = D  then Promotion_grade = C & Section_team= team2
             If Grade = A  then Promotion_grade = A+ & Section_team= team3
```

I can add one column for first two conditions. But I don't know for the rest conditions.

```
def addCols(data):
   data = (data.withColumn('Promotion_grade', F.when(data.Section  =='Admin', 'B')
                                                .when(data.Section  =='Account', 'A')
                                                .otherwise('Not applicable')))
   return data
```

Please someone can help me in this? May be the way I'm doing is wrong. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can nest `when` conditions to handle nested conditions.

### Working Example

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

data = [("Admin", "C", ), 
        ("Account", "B", ), 
        ("IT", "B", ),
        ("IT", "C", ),
        ("IT", "D", ),
        ("IT", "A", ),]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ("Section", "Grade", ))

# Define Promotion Grade conditions for IT Section
it_promotion_grade = (F.when(F.col("Grade") == "C", "B")
                       .when(F.col("Grade") == "D", "C")
                       .when(F.col("Grade") == "A", "A+")
                       .otherwise("Not applicable"))

# Define Section Team conditions for IT Section
it_section_team = (F.when(F.col("Grade") == "C", "team1")
                    .when(F.col("Grade") == "D", "team2")
                    .when(F.col("Grade") == "A", "team3")
                    .otherwise("Not applicable"))

(df.withColumn("Promotion_grade", F.when(F.col("Section") == "Admin", "B")
                                  .when(F.col("Section") == "Account", "A")
                                  .when(F.col("Section") == "IT", it_promotion_grade)
                                  .otherwise("Not applicable"))
    .withColumn("Section_team", F.when(F.col("Section") == "IT", it_section_team)
                     .otherwise("Not applicable"))
    .show())
```

### Output

```
+-------+-----+---------------+--------------+
|Section|Grade|Promotion_grade|  Section_team|
+-------+-----+---------------+--------------+
|  Admin|    C|              B|Not applicable|
|Account|    B|              A|Not applicable|
|     IT|    B| Not applicable|Not applicable|
|     IT|    C|              B|         team1|
|     IT|    D|              C|         team2|
|     IT|    A|             A+|         team3|
+-------+-----+---------------+--------------+
```

Comment: OMG, very much clear!! thanks a lot.